# Documentation for meteor create command

Tags: angular, meteor

In the [tutorial for creating a Meteor app using Angular 2](https://www.angular-meteor.com/tutorials/socially/angular2/bootstrapping#meteorsetup), you are asked to execute the following command in a Terminal window:

```
meteor create --example angular2-boilerplate socially
```

I have been unable to find any documentation that explains the various options for the `meteor create` command, that would give insight into what the `--example angular2-boilerplate` arguments are doing. The closest I have found is in the [Meteor docs for the commandline](https://docs.meteor.com/commandline.html#meteorcreate), but this only mentions a `--package` option, with no further details.

Can you explain all the options available with `meteor create`, and how they work?

Comment: `meteor help create`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Meteor CLI tool contains its own documentation.

You could use `meteor help` (or the more standard `meteor --help` or `meteor -h`) to get the general command list. Note the line at the bottom.

```
$ meteor help
Usage: meteor [--release <release>] [--help] <command> [args]
       meteor help <command>
       meteor [--version] [--arch]

With no arguments, 'meteor' runs the project in the current
directory in local development mode. You can run it from the root
directory of the project or from any subdirectory.

Use 'meteor create <path>' to create a new Meteor project.

Commands:
   run                [default] Run this project in local development mode.
   debug              Run the project, but suspend the server process for debugging.
   create             Create a new project.
...
   show               Show detailed information about a release or package.

See 'meteor help <command>' for details on a command.
```

So, for help with the `create` command, you should type:

```
$ meteor help create
Usage: meteor create [--release <release>] <path>
       meteor create [--release <release>] --example <example_name> [<path>]
       meteor create --list
       meteor create --package [<package_name>]

Make a subdirectory named <path> if it doesn't exist and create a new Meteor app
there. You can pass an absolute path, relative path, or '.' for the current
directory.

With the --package option, creates a Meteor package instead of an app. If you're
in an app, the package will go in the app's top-level 'packages' directory;
otherwise it will be created in the current directory.

The app will use the release of Meteor specified with the --release
option, or the latest available version if the option is not specified. (A
package created in an app, will be created using the application's version of
meteor and a package created outside a meteor app will use the latest release).

You can pass --example to start off with a copy of one of the Meteor
sample applications. Use --list to see the available examples. There are
currently no package examples.

Options:
  --package  Create a new meteor package instead of an app.
  --example  Example template to use.
  --list     Show list of available examples.
```

and the list of examples:

```
$ meteor create --list
Available examples:
  clock: https://github.com/meteor/clock      
  leaderboard: https://github.com/meteor/leaderboard
  localmarket: https://github.com/meteor/localmarket
  simple-todos: https://github.com/meteor/simple-todos
  simple-todos-react: https://github.com/meteor/simple-todos-react
  simple-todos-angular: https://github.com/meteor/simple-todos-angular
  todos: https://github.com/meteor/todos      
  todos-react: https://github.com/meteor/todos#react
  angular2-boilerplate: https://github.com/bsliran/angular2-meteor-base

To create an example, simply git clone the relevant repository and branch (run
'meteor create --example <name>'  to see the full command).
```

(this is the output for Meteor v1.4.2)

Answer (score 1):

`meteor create <project>`...

`--example angular2-boilerplate` just pulls code  from here https://github.com/Urigo/angular2-meteor-base  rather than making a skelton, standard meteor app

Your project name is `socially`